# Minimum eigenvalue of sums of positive semi-definite matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, positive-definite, positive-semidefinite

Suppose $A_1,A_2$ are positive definite matrices such that $\lambda_{min}(A_1) \leq \lambda_{min}(A_2)$ where $\lambda_{min}(.)$ denotes the minimum eigenvalue. Let $B$ be a positive semi-definite matrix. Is it true that $\lambda_{min}(A_1+B) \leq \lambda_{min}(A_2+B)$?

Comment: Yes.  Hint: for a Hermitian matrix $A$, the minimum eigenvalue is the minimum of $\langle Av, v \rangle$ over all unit vectors $v$.

Answer (score 2):

No. Counterexample: consider $A_1=\pmatrix{1\\ &2}$ and $A_2=B=\pmatrix{2\\ &1}$.

Comment: thanks, what if $\lambda_{min}(A_1)< \lambda_{min}(A_2)$?

Comment: @Sanand It doesn't matter. The counterexample still works if you replace the $1$ in $A_1$ by $1-\epsilon$ for some small $\epsilon>0$.

Comment: yes, thanks I found a counterexample already inspired by your previous one!!

Comment: @user1551 In addition to OP's conditions, if we have $A_2 - A_1 > 0$, does that imply what he needs?

Comment: @dineshdileep If $A_2-A_1>0$, then $(A_2+B)-(A_1+B)>0$, so the minimum eigenvalue of $A_2+B$ dominates that of $A_1+B$.